# Find % using LIKE

Tags: sql-server

I need to find `%` in a column. I tried the following

```
SELECT  *
FROM    <table>
WHERE   <column> LIKE '%%%'
```

But, all rows are listed. How to find the rows only with `% using LIKE` condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be appropriate:

```
select  * 
FROM    <table>
WHERE   <column> LIKE '%[%]%'
```

Answer (score 7):

Try following format:

```
select  * 
FROM    <table>
WHERE   <column> LIKE '%/%%' ESCAPE '/'
```

You can also use `%[%]%` in your like: [Anand Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24881307/1407421)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use \ to escape the percentage. Try the following:

```
select * from table where column like '%\%%';
```

Comment: Note that the tag SLQ Server was added to the question after.  Jesuraja, you should not ping the person trying to help you for your failing.  BatAnna cannot comment to you.

Comment: @BatAnna Did you try? Is it working? Which version? It is not at all working.